# CSS border width doubled in IE

Tags: css

got problems with my CSS style.

border widths doubled in IE, but in Mozilla, Opera, Safari, its ok.

here's my code:

```
.subPane{
border: #FF33FF thin dashed;
}
```

'thin' is like 1px in width, but when viewed in IE, its like 2px already.

:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
.subPane{
border: 1px dashed #FF33FF;
}
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-border

Answer (score 3):

You might just want to specify the width as 1px rather than using a qualitative label. This will be respected by all browsers.

Comment: Lol - that is fine.  Philippe gave a nice link as well so he deserves the points.  Thanks for feedback though - not enough questions are followed up like this so I appreciated it.